# Getting 0 from checkbox value in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a value( 1 or 0) from a checkbox using `FormCollection`. But even I check it I get 0 in debugger mode.

Here, is the checkbox.

```
<label class="form-check-label">
     <input id="UbankInsurance" name="UbankInsurance" value="1" type="checkbox"/> Yes
</label>
```

and here is the method to collect it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection fc)
{
   int ublInsurance = Convert.ToInt32(fc["UbankInsurance"]);
}
```

and further im going to pass this value to a database column that has a `bit` Data type

Comment: Have you actually put your checkbox in a form? If so, please show us your form

Comment: May be duplicate  id or name "UbankInsurance" on form please check once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fairly correct, so I suppose you have not passed your checkbox in a `form` to begin with. Furthermore you need to check that value for `null`. If a checkbox is checked, the value `"1"` is submitted as a string. If it is unchecked, the value null will be returned.

Here is a working example:

```
<h3>Submitted value: @TempData["val"]</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("GetCheckbox", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input id="UbankInsurance" name="UbankInsurance" value="1" type="checkbox" />
        Yes
    </label>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Controller Method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCheckbox(FormCollection form)
{
    var checkboxChecked = form["UbankInsurance"]; //get the checkbox value
    if(checkboxChecked == null) //if it is unchecked it will be null
    {
        checkboxChecked = "0"; //set it to a parsable value instead
    }
    //convert 0 or 1 to int and return it to view
    TempData["val"] = Convert.ToInt32(checkboxChecked); 
    return View("Index");
}
```

Please not, that I have used the HomeController in a demo application, so make sure you fill in your actual values in terms of action methods and controller names.